# Cow sacrifice over bull at anointing ceremony

Tags: david, sacrifice, samuel

1 Sh'mu'el 16v2, God tells the prophet to take a female cow specifically for the sacrifice that was going to take place at David's anointing. Any reason why it had to be a "female cow" rather than just a cow or a bull as would be anticipated?

1 Samuel 16:2-3 NIV

> The Lord said, “Take a heifer with you and say, ‘I have come to sacrifice to the Lord.’
> Invite Jesse to the sacrifice, and I will show you what to do. You are to anoint for me the one I indicate.”